# Solve differential equation with three variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$$z''+y'= \cos (x)$$

$$y''-z= \sin (x)$$

with $z(0)=1$, $z'(0)=-1$, $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$.

These differential equations involves three variables $x, y, z$. Can someone drop a hint on how to start this.

Comment: For clarification, your notation $y' = \frac{dy}{dt}$, right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Hang on. Are $y$ and $z$ functions of $x$, or are $x$, $y$, and $z$ all functions of another independent variable, call it $t$?

Comment: Are we sure y and z are functions of t and not of x?

Comment: I was told that they are a function of t

Comment: it dosent make sense you have initial conditions for y and z but not for x... I think that the derivative is taken wrt x  and you have only tw equations instead of three...

Comment: I think so too, there are no initial conditions for x and only two equations. We can help if this is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to assume $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$ since there are only two equations and no initial conditions on $x$ are provided.

Here's a hint. Differentiate the first equation
$$ z''' + y'' = -\sin x $$

Subtract this from the second equation to get
$$ z'''+ z = -2\sin x $$

This is a non-homogeneous linear ODE that you can solve.